# How to logout authenticated user in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

Apologize for the noob question. Just beginning to learn servicestack. I'm using a self-hosted console application with Razor for my view engine, the "RegistrationFeature" plugin for registrations and CredentialsAuthProvider for authentication via form post to allow users to login.

The [SocialBootStrap](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi) application uses MVC 3 and does a "FormsAuthentication.SignOut()" to allow users to  logout. Given that I'm using a self hosted application,  I created a LogoutService that simply does a Request.RemoveSession() and that appears to work.

Is this the right way to log out a user's session ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is an explicit logout service i.e. `/auth/logout` as part of the [ServiceStack's Authentication support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) that you should use instead.

You can do a GET or POST to `/auth/logout` or if you're using C# client you can logout with:

```
client.Post(new Authenticate { provider = "logout" });
```

Comment: Thank you, wow that was under 20 minutes to get an answer :) !

Comment: You're welcome :) This Q just happened to be there when I was doing my periodic rounds - you wont always be that lucky :)

Comment: Note that this magical service is not referenced anywhere (or at least not any more) on the Authentication wiki page.

Answer (score 6):

On ServiceStack v4 you will need this line instead.

```
client.Post(new Authenticate { provider = AuthenticateService.LogoutAction });
```