# Can't logout user with basic authentication in ServiceStack

Tags: authentication, servicestack, servicestack-auth

I'm currently trying to implement ServiceStack's authentication plugin but I'm having trouble in logging out a user after they have logged in. I've seen from this thread:

[How to logout authenticated user in ServiceStack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116882/how-to-logout-authenticated-user-in-servicestack)

that you should be able to make the request `auth/logout`. However I'm still logged in at this point. I also tried to login as an invalid user `/auth?username=&password=` but to no avail.

The strange thing is these methods have worked from me on very rare occasions but I haven't found the reason why. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I just tried out the above requests in Fiddler and noticed I'm getting back a 401. I suppose that should be expected when trying to login as an invalid user but why is it the case for the logout request?

Comment: Using Fiddler, What's the error message you're getting when trying to logout? is it a "400 Not Empty"?

Comment: @Rachid Its a 401 - Unauthorized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is the same case of username/password validation being triggered on logout. you can overcome this issue by rolling out you own `CustomAuthProvider` if you're not already doing so. In the validation section you should exclude the logout as a provider.

```
public class CustomAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    private class CredentialsAuthValidator : AbstractValidator<Authenticate>
    {
        public CredentialsAuthValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.UserName)
                    .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Username Required")
                    .When(d => d.provider != "logout");

            RuleFor(x => x.Password)
                    .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Password Required")
                    .When(d => d.provider != "logout");
        }
    }

    public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Authenticate request)
    {
        new CredentialsAuthValidator().ValidateAndThrow(request);
        return Authenticate(authService, session, request.UserName, request.Password, request.Continue);
    }
}
```

You will also need to register the CustomAuthProvider

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
       new CustomAuthProvider()
    }) { HtmlRedirect = null });
```

Note: you are missing the provider in `/auth/{provider}?username=&password=`

Comment: Yes this works perfectly for me, thank you. To clarify for other people, I am able to logout with "auth/logout" and I'm able to login with "auth?username={username}&password={password}" (Note: I do not need to logout first to login as a different user). I'm left confused however why I was having this problem when using the BasicAuthProvider. I was under the impression it was simple to logout. A bug perhaps?